# increasing a char array value by one and display the Ascii represented value

Tags: c

being a total newbie;
I am using an embedded c IDE called mikro C.
I have a char array "AA 75 49 D7"
which is displayed as is in Ascii.
I would like to increase char array by one with each loop.
IE:"AA 75 49 D7"
   "AA 75 49 D8"
  .....
  "AA 75 49 E0"
  "AA 75 49 E1"
 ....
  "AA 75 4A 00"
  "AA 75 4A 01"
etc until ""FF FF FF FF"
how would go about this.

I have tried to formulate some code. but everytime it becomes long winded.
please see my last attempt which only increases the last char 7.

```
 unsigned char Dat16_2[]="123450";
 unsigned int add_1;
 unsigned int len;

      len=strlen(Dat16_2); 
      if (Dat16_2[len-Add_1] >='G'){
          Add_1++;
          Dat16_2[len-Add_1]='0';
          NewLine();
          Uart2_write_text(Dat16_2);
       }else
       if (Dat16_2[len-Add_1] >= 'A' &&  Dat16_2[len-Add_1] <= 'F') {  
           NewLine();
           Uart2_write_text(Dat16_2);
       } else
       if (Dat16_2[len-Add_1] >= '0' && Dat16_2[len-Add_1] <= '9') {
           NewLine();
           Uart2_write_text(Dat16_2);
          }
          Dat16_2[len-Add_1]=Dat16_2[len-Add_1]+1;
       }
```

Comment: Introduce a "carry" variable, set it to `0` or `1` in the increment of the least significant value... then propagate left until it becomes `0` or the most significant value is reached.

Comment: Loop over the raw integer values and convert to ASCII hex as needed. If you have a decent terminal program, it can even read raw hex from UART and then there's no need to convert anything.

Comment: Thanks guys but do you have an example because i am missing something.

Comment: If I add an if statement to look for 'F' then i can increase the next variable but then I have to filter out all the chars I don't need again:if( Dat16_2[len-Add_1]=='F'){

            Dat16_2[len-(Add_1+1)]=Dat16_2[len-(Add_1+1)]+1;
             }